# Invisible mounting hardware for a particular kind of wall unit

Tags: mounting

I'm looking to build my own version of this wall unit: https://retrorenovation.com/2012/05/10/barzilay-multispan-vertical-storage-system-valuable-scandinavian-modern-wall-unit-design/

I think I know how I'm going to do the cabinets and the shelving, but the one thing that I can't figure out is how to mount the top of the large wood L-shaped beams flush to the wall with no hardware showing, and no pocket holes.

Well, that's not accurate. I'd like to use a mount kind of like how the rear view mirror of your car mounts to the windshield: that sort of U shaped one where the mirror slides down onto another U shaped piece, but I have no idea what that kind of mount is called. I feel like this would be the best solution to prevent lateral movement of the brackets.

So if you know what that kind of mount is called or if you know of a better way to mount this thing, let me know.

Comment: there could be a threaded stud screwed to the wall ... the mounting nut could be accessible from the top

Comment: In that particular structure, the tops of the L-beams do not need to be anchored to the wall at all. The geometry is such that the center of gravity of the cabinets is behind the bottom legs, and the whole structure is simply leaning against the wall. Just put some slip-resistant pads there.

Comment: @DaveTweed The cabinets are not hard-fastened to the beams, so if a young child (say my 3 year old daughter) were to somehow manage to kick the beam hard enough to cause it to dislodge from the cabinet, the whole thing would, indeed, come crashing down. Anchoring it to the wall wouldn't prevent this entirely (a hard and dedicated enough kick would probably still do the trick) but it would prevent it on accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of fasteners that you want are not common, so you're going to need to do a little digging, and focus on brackets used in furniture manufacture.  One idea I had are bed rail brackets.  Some might be too large, but this will give you a starting point for more research:

[image: Bed rail fastener]

*[Bed rail bracket](https://jwright.com/product/slide-bed-fasteners-2/)*

There is another style [here at Rockler](https://www.rockler.com/locking-safety-bed-rail-brackets).

Now, these are sold in wholesale quantities, so I don't expect this link to directly help you, but this is another style of bracket you can find with some more looking:

[image: hidden bracket]

*[AliExpress bracket](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32952902060.html)*

Comment: Great ideas! The bed rail brackets is _very_ smart. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 2):

I think what you may be referencing is called a *French Cleat*:

[image]

Comment: But note that the cleat allows horizontal movement, something that the OP seems to want to prevent. I've used this method to mount some fairly heavy wall cabinets, and the advantage is that you can be sure that the wall cleat is anchored directly to the wall studs without worrying about how they align with the cabinet itself. Note that the angle on the cleat in your diagram is rather extreme -- 10 to 20 degrees would be more typical.

Comment: Correct, @DaveTweed , I am definitely wary of lateral movement in this particular case. In my initial research, though, I did happen across French cleats, which is something I'll definitely remember for future projects.

Comment: You can -very- easily and simply tweak this fitting to your needs by adding stops on the cleats. For example, a dowel in one and a hole in the other

Comment: Yes, but the beam would not be flush with the wall anyway, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Keyhole bracket

They come in different shapes and sizes, you should be able to find the shape and size you need

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a keyhole bracket that has a bespoke "male/female" setup? (rather than utilizing a screw or nail or some such standard fastener). I"m looking for a very tight fit

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. You can recess a round keyhole fitting so that it is flush or slightly inside the piece that will attach to the wall, then use a standard fastener at the wall

Comment: A tight, secure fit is paramount here. It should allow no movement once secured. I don't believe using hardware that isn't designed to fit tightly together would be sufficient. These are primary support beams for shelving.

Comment: Fair enough but consider you criteria that has severally limited your options, you might have to give something somewhere. Note that the bevel of a flat head screw is a wedge that provides the secure fit into these fittings, it can be very finely tuned by screwing in or out to adjust the depth.

Comment: That is true, and certainly worth the consideration! Thanks for the idea!